# How To Add Delay Before Presenting Second Alert View

Tags: ios, uialertview

Im displaying two Alert Views one after another in succession with the following:

-IBAction

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"my message"     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert setDelegate:self];

[alert show];




}

- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
{

[alertView setTitle:@"My new title"];
[alertView setMessage:@"My new message"];

}
```

The transition from the first Alert View to the second is so fast the user would not have time to read the fist message.  Could someone advise how to add a delay between the Alerts. I Think I need to implement an NSTimer but implementing this is where I could use some advice.

Comment: Use the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol method that is called when the alert view is **dismissed**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest using `dispatch_after`, which can be inlined:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     // code to be executed on the main queue after delay 
});
```

Comment: Thank you that works a treat, thats saved to my code snippets!

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method:

```
- (void)alertView
{
    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Get Ready!" message:nil     delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissStartAlert:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:5];
}

-(void)dismissStartAlert:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [alertView setTitle:@"My new title"];
    [alertView setMessage:@"My new message"];
    [alert show];
}
```